# was this a personal advice question?

Tags: discussion

this question was deleted:

https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/15938/what-methods-of-healing-suturing-of-torn-male-internal-urethral-sphincter-are-th :

> **what methods of healing/suturing of torn male internal urethral sphincter are there? [closed]**
>
> i have seen in [an article][1] that it is possible to suture internal
>   urethral sphincter by surgical access from bottom of body, from
>   between anal opening and penis and legs.
>
> is there other methods?
>
> what if only internal urethral sphincter is torn, while surrounding
>   tissues are ok? can suturing be made through cystoscope sheath(?)?
>
> [1]: https://www.hindawi.com/journals/criu/2014/176073/

why it was deleted?

-- close reason was this:

> "Questions requesting personal medical advice are off-topic here.
>   Nobody here can properly address your health issues. Such questions
>   should be taken to your personal physician who can examine you and
>   access your full medical records. For more information, please see
>   this meta post." – Carey Gregory, Graham Chiu, Narusan, LangLangC,
>   Chris Rogers

-- and there were 2 comments:

> This is your third question about urethral sphincter repair, one of
>   which was already closed as a request for medical advice. You clearly
>   need to consult a urologist. We cannot and will not provide medical
>   advice. – Carey Gregory Apr 13 at 23:44
>
> @CareyGregory do not you see that question asks for list of methods?
>   where do you see personal answer? – qdinar Apr 14 at 12:25

-- i think, referring to other questions of mine to prove that this is actually a personal advice question is not ok. and even that question was edited by me, to make it "general", meaning not personal, question. btw, if you would think think in that way, any such general, good question on this site can be really a personal question, but just carefully asked to hide that it is "personal".

btw, earlier, in comments to my other question, there were other comments, that has shown that maybe such question is ok:

> ... The only way to save it would be to delete all the personal
>   details and ask how urethral sphincter dysfunction is treated. – Carey
>   Gregory Apr 1 at 20:24

-- this comment even allows a more general question than the quoted above.

> ... Bladder voiding dysfunction is rarely from a torn sphincter, and
>   even in that rare case, speculating how to heal a torn sphincter would
>   require the exact mechanism of such injury, how long, medical history,
>   medications, symptoms, test results... THAT is personalized by
>   definition, not suited for SE. This question will remain closed,
>   please leave it. See a urologist with your questions, they can explain
>   what is going on in your specific case and answer your questions. We
>   wish you well but can't help here. – DoctorWhom Apr 9 at 2:44

-- this comment disallowed this my question, but i am not sure he was right.

would not it possible to divide my this question, quoted above, to 2 subquestions: 1) asking about list of common methods of healing of muscules and 2) asking about common methods of access to internal urethral sphincter?

-- if so, moderators could ask to divide my question to 2 questions, or, that 2 questions could be answered together...

-- so, i think, the close reason saying "requesting personal medical advice" was not correct. maybe this quesion should have been deleted with other close reason, though.

Comment: Once it was closed, it was automatically removed by the system after a period of time.

Comment: I disagree that it's not okay to consider other recent questions you've asked on a single topic. Suppose someone comes along and says they have X disease, and they ask how to treat it, but their question gets closed because it's a request for medical advice. Well, shortly they post again asking how X disease is treated. It's clearly still a request for medical advice and if I answer it I **know** I'm giving someone medical advice. That's just gaming the system. It's an attempt to circumvent the rules by adhering to the letter of the law but not the intent.

Comment: circumventing may be bad sometimes, for example for religion or state rules. but why it is bad here? i think denying it is useless for this site. they can be able to read different medical info from different places themselves and make wrong medical decision themselves. and you are not responsible for what they do! they are responsible for believing to any advice they get! i think this site's intention should be making medical science questions. preventing people from getting wrong advice and believing to it and making things worse should not be its intention because it is ineffective...

Comment: I think you underestimate how many people will take medical advice from strangers on the internet and act on it, especially if it's what they want to hear. We choose not to be a source of such advice.

Answer (score 4):

The answer to your question as it is written would be "It depends", because it depends on the medical background.

Posts with the answer "It depends" should be closed as primarily opinion-based. In order to make this question scientific and not just opinion-based, you would have to edit in personal medical background, which would have made the question a request for personal medical advice and still off-topic. Really, we had to choose between opinion-based and too personal. I think both are suited in this situation.

This is a problem we are well aware off. There are certain types of questions (mostly concerned with a problem directly related to a medical case (be it you or other patients) that simply can't be covered here on Health.SE. This is due to the nature of this site.